# Import SQLAlchemy into my project

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy

#### Environment:

- Python 2.7.5
- SQLAlchemy 0.9.6

#### What I've done:

I want to include the SQLAlchemy source into my project for different reasons. The main reason is to avoid any virtual environments for my users later.

Okay my structure looks like this:

```
$ tree . -L 2
myapp
├── libs
│   ├── ...
│   └── sqlalchemy
├── myapp
│   └── ...
└── MyApp.py
```

Okay I add the `libs` path to the system path.

```
### MyApp.py
# ...
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
LIBRARY_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'libs')
sys.path.append(LIBRARY_DIR)
# ...
```

When I now try to import from `libs.sqlalchemy.orm`

```
from libs.sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
```

I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../myapp/MyApp.py", line 13, in <module>
    from libs.sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
  File "/.../myapp/libs/sqlalchemy/orm/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import strategies as _strategies
  File "/.../myapp/libs/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py", line 301, in <module>
    @properties.RelationshipProperty.strategy_for(lazy="noload")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RelationshipProperty'
```

This is where the traceback points to

```
### ./libs/sqlalchemy/orm/strategies.py
@log.class_logger
@properties.RelationshipProperty.strategy_for(lazy="noload") # <- here
@properties.RelationshipProperty.strategy_for(lazy=None)
class NoLoader(AbstractRelationshipLoader):
    # ...
```

#### Actual question:

What do I have missed / done wrong?
I've downloaded the tar.gz from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SQLAlchemy/0.9.6) and copied the lib/sqlalchemy folder to my lib path

Comment: Your idea will work only for the most simple use cases for various reasons. You should either stick to virtualenv or a similar tool or check out one of the many python packaging tools available. Which one to choose depends on your OS, use case, ... There are many, but in my experience, none is perfect.

Comment: Once again, it's not going to work for alchmemy because of native libs that come with it.

Answer (score 3):

Just unpackig tar file is not going to work for alchemy, because it has native libraries that need to be compiled, so you can

```
sudo pip install alchemy or
untar your tar.gz and run "python setup.py install"
```

This is what "pip install" is doing:

```
Installing collected packages: sqlalchemy
  Running setup.py install for sqlalchemy
    building 'sqlalchemy.cprocessors' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.o
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -g build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/processors.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/sqlalchemy/cprocessors.so
    building 'sqlalchemy.cresultproxy' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.o
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -g build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/resultproxy.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/sqlalchemy/cresultproxy.so
    building 'sqlalchemy.cutils' extension
    /usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/utils.o
    /usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -g build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/lib/sqlalchemy/cextension/utils.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/sqlalchemy/cutils.so
```

Comment: That's not really accurate, you can install a pure-python implementation of sqlalchemy. It'll just be slower without the c extensions. See this: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/intro.html#installing-the-c-extensions

Comment: OP is apparently missing dependencies. If he wants to dump everything to his source tree, he should take care of dependencies. In the standard package that I worked with, it's native C libs, in the case that you have quoted, it can be something else, but he would need to put it to his source tree anyway. All dependencies should be described in setup.py files, so it's doable for pure Python version, but the qs was different - "what have I done wrong". The short answer is - you've missed dependencies.